# The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/hera pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ppa, repositories

How can I remove this repo(`https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/hera`) from the system?

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                
The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/hera pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have tried doing like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/hera/ppa
```

its not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the supported codenames for postgresql repository, use the following command:

```
curl -SsL https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/ |awk -F'"' 'FNR >2 {print $2}'
```

sample output:

```
bionic/
bullseye/
buster/
disco/
eoan/
focal/
groovy/
stretch/
xenial/
README
```

As you can see `hera` isn't listed, it is not a valid codename. Use `bionic` codename instead:

```
sudo curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/bionic pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list'
sudo  apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to the files app and entering this directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d' to find your repo? From what I've seen in other distros yours should be there.